# Loop through folder tree and execute bat file in subfolders in parallel(accessing the files in the subfolder)

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am trying to have a bat file in `folder1` which is the parent folder, and this bat file which named `run.bat` will loop through all subfolders, and invoke a bat file named `child.bat` in parallel, however, these `child.bat` will have to access another files in the same folder.

For example:

```
Folder1 (have run.bat)
  |
  |_______Folder2
  |           |
  |           |_______aa.txt
  |           |
  |           |_______child.bat
  |
  |_______Folder3
            |
            |_______bb.txt
            |
            |_______child.bat
```

The `child.bat` which in `Folder2`, the content is :

```
type aa.txt
```

The `child.bat` which in `Folder3`, the content is :

```
type bb.txt
```

I know there are questions already there on how to loop though subfolders, and run bat file in subfolder. But my question is, the bat file have to access other files which located in the same child folder. and if we don't enter subfolder (`cd subfolder`), the `child.bat` will not successfully executed. Here is the content of `run.bat` that I tried:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%i in (*) do ( 
   cd %%i
   start "%%i\child.bat"
  )
```

However, failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your extra information in the comments, this should work for you.

```
@echo off
FOR /d /r %%i IN (*) DO (
   if exist "%%i\child.bat" start "" /d "%%i" "%comspec%" /c "child.bat"
)
```

Comment: Thank you foxidrive. But the cmd window which popped out disappeared very quickly. I can't see the results for the child.bat in the new cmd window.

Comment: Can you describe how it failed?  I'm curious why it didn't work.

Comment: Well. When I run your script, just saw window popped out, and disappeared very quickly. At the same time, there isn't any results displayed on the main cmd window.

Comment: If I add pushd and popd to your scritp, like this 
`@echo off FOR /d /r %%i IN (*) DO ( pushd "%%i" if exist "%%i\child.bat" start "" /d "%%i" "%comspec%" /c "child.bat" popd )`

 failed again.

Comment: It doesn't need pushd/popd because the `start` command includes the function.  Put `pause` as the very last line and try it.  Make sure you spell `child.bat` correctly in both places if you change it.

Comment: Thank you bringing it out, I make sure that child.bat spelled correctly in both places. And If I put `pause` at the very end, the newly window popped out and disappeared very quickly like before. But there are 2 lines of messages displayed on the main window.
`Press any key to continue . . .`
`Press any key to continue . . .`
I guess these 2 guys are for folder2 and folder3.

Comment: Change `start` to `echo start` and you will see all the commands that would be launched.  I tested it here and it works - the actual function of child.bat is unknown.

Comment: It suddenly occurred to me that the newly opened window flashed very quickly was just because child.bat executed very fast. Then I added `pasue` to the very end of the last line of child.bat, I can see very clearly on the behavior. Your script works. Great.
Thank you so much for your time and help.
I will mark your answer as accepted answer.
Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the script must be able to consistently change directories from the same place where the `for` loop was invoked.  Just saving the current folder (via a `pushd`) and restoring it after the child invocation (via `popd`) should be enough.

```
@echo off
FOR /d /r %%i IN (*) DO (
   pushd "%%i"
   call "child.bat"
   popd
)
```

Comment: `if exist "child.bat" call "child.bat"` <--- this may be a better line to use.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have to say that, it works.
But actually in my case, I have to invoke child.bat in parallel. That is why I use "start". And if I use start, it didn't work.
`@echo off
FOR /d /r %%i IN (*) DO (
   pushd "%%i"
   start "child.bat"
   popd
)`